# Suppress warning output on manage.py dumpdata?

Tags: django

I'm using django's dumpdata and loaddata commands to facilitate  some data exports.  However I currently have some unresolved deprecation warnings and so when I write the output of dumpdata to a file the warnings end up at the top of the file and I must manually clean up the dump files every time.  Is there any way to suppress or avoid the warnings do that the output of dumpdata is legitimate json without having to manually remove the warning text each time?

Comment: Have you tried setting `--verbosity`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---verbosity

Comment: Yes.  Should have mentioned that in my question. No apparent effect on the warning output, which is unfortunate

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like it just might not be possible to surpress warnings in that management command.

Comment: Looks like this the warnings are actually output to stderr not stdout, so I think with a standard > or >> the warnings actually won't end up in the output of dumpdata (although I haven't tested this extensively). Without going to further detail as to why, I'm re-routing stderr to stdout on this particular system and this appears to be a side-effect of that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can also suppress warnings without having to insert code anywhere, by flags on the python interpreter

eg

```
python -Wi manage.py dumpdata
```

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W

Answer (score 6):

You could try overriding [`warning.showwarning`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning). Put the following code somewhere that will be imported when you `dumpdata` (such as your `settings.py`):

```
import warnings
warnings.showwarning = lambda *x: None
```

Comment: Looks like there is also a cleaner more approved technique described in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings).